# make an event occur on an element the first time clicked but have that event fire again only if another element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, logic

lets say i have 5 span element. each element has an event listener like `

```
$('.option1').on("click", function(){
    option1()
})
```

the event for option 1 is also the default event that occurs on page load so if no other options are clicked you will not be able to make the event because the event is already going on and another option wasn't chosen. if the user chooses another option then  they could choose option1 . similar thing will happen with a click on the other options. lets say you chose option5 the event should occur once. If you click on the option 5 again no event should fire but if you click on option 2 or another option then click on option5, option 5 event should fire. the same thing for all options accept the first option. the first option should not fire on the first click because it is default. it should only fire after another option was pressed.

I tried doing something like putting a value in the other options and checking to see if in the current options that is being fired has the values that was set in the other options and if it was, fire the event and reset the options. I had problems with the logic. what is your solution?

below is just a template you may or may not want to use. it just has the span elements. the functions and the events.

```
        $(document).ready( function(){
        var o2Clicked =[]
         function option1(){
            alert("option1 function")
        }
        function option2(){
            alert("option2 function")
        }
        function option3(){
            alert("option3 function")
        }
        function option4(){
            alert("option4 function")
        }
        function option5(){
            alert("option5 function")
        }
        //call function for default
        option1()
        $('.option1').on("click", function(){
            option1()
        })

        $('.option2').on("click", function(){
            //o1Cliced[0] = 1
            option2()
        })
        $('.option3').on("click", function(){
            o2Clicked[0] =2
            option3()
        })
        $('.option4').on("click", function(){
            o2Clicked[0] =3
            option4()
        })
        $('.option5').on("click", function(){
            o2Clicked[0] =4
            option5()
          })

    });
```

html

```
<span class="option1">option1</span>
<span class="option2">option2</span>
<span class="option3">option3</span>
<span class="option4">option4</span>
<span class="option5">option5</span>
```

style

```
span{
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

Comment: I would just use classes, click once add class, if click and class present do nothing else toggle class.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare some variable and change its value between "true" and "false" for keep tracking condition.

For example:

```js
var specialvar = false;

$('#one').on('click', function(){
  if(!specialvar) {
    alert('buttons 2 and 3 will now work');  
    specialvar = true;
  }
});

$('#two').on('click', function() {
  if(specialvar) {
    alert('only button 1 will now work');
    specialvar = false;
  }  
});
  
$('#three').on('click', function() {
  if(specialvar) {
      alert('i just work if var is true');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one" href="#">1</button>
<button id="two" href="#">2</button>
<button id="three" href="#">3</button>
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. this is helpful but im not sure if it is for my specific case. what you have is a button that activates other button functionality. if i click on button 3 again and again it fires the event again and again it should fire the event only after  button3 was clicked after another button was clicked and that button's event was fired . you have a good way of deactivating buttons. but Im not sure it's good for my requirements.

Comment: buttons 3 fires event again and again because it doesnt change specialvar as other buttons do. 
If you add :    specialvar = false;   after alert  - button3 will not work till you click button1.

Comment: I see that but I still cant get the functionality i want using your way. after you click on 1, 3 activates and you're able to click on it all day and get the event. that's not good. you should only be able to get the event after you click on the other buttons and when button 3 is clicked again.

Comment: i see your edit.  i tried setting specialvar = false and your right `button3 will not work till you click button1"`but what about button 2. that's what im trying to get at it. button 3 should not work again until any other button was clicked not just the first on or second one. if i press  button2, 3 will not work when it should. depperm's answer got the functionality  right but I want to see if you could get it right using your method with flagging(i think that's what its called) setting true false to vars..no pressure.

Comment: you may add one more speciale variable to track any condition. it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

Like my comment I'd use a class to keep track of which span has been clicked.

```js
$('span').on('click',function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
    $('span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    alert($(this).text()+' function');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="option1">option1</span>
<span class="option2">option2</span>
<span class="option3">option3</span>
<span class="option4">option4</span>
<span class="option5">option5</span>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Interesting. Just to clarify `$('span').removeClass('active');` removes the class from all spans and ` $(this).addClass('active');` adds the class to the specific span that was clicked. If you click on the span again it wont  fire the event because it has the active class. but it really will fire the click event but not the add class and remove class methods. thanks for your help. I hope i understand

Comment: that is correct, the click event always fires but only does something if the span clicked isn't active.